# Spring boot service make a call to ms graph without a user login

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

So i have registered an app in Azure AD, with relevant scopes and client secret. I want my spring boot application to make calls to obtain information about users. So this is really the service making the call, no need for user to login. With a secret set i thought it would be possible to do this. Obtain a token and make a call.

```
spring:
 cloud:
   azure:
     active-directory:
       enabled: true
       profile:
         tenant-id: <tenant-ID-registered-by-application>
       credential:
         client-id: <web-API-A-client-ID>
         client-secret: <web-API-A-client-secret>
       app-id-uri: <web-API-A-app-ID-URI>
       authorization-clients:
         graph:
           scopes:
              - https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

And the controller is as follows:

```
@GetMapping("call-graph")
public String callGraph(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("graph") OAuth2AuthorizedClient graph) {
GraphServiceClient client = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new GraphAuthenticationProvider(graphAuthorizedClient))
                .buildClient();
   return callMicrosoftGraphMeEndpoint(client);
}
```

GraphAuthenicationProvider

```
  private static class GraphAuthenticationProvider
            extends BaseAuthenticationProvider {

        private OAuth2AuthorizedClient graphAuthorizedClient;

        /**
         * Set up the GraphAuthenticationProvider. Allows accessToken to be
         * used by GraphServiceClient through the interface IAuthenticationProvider
         *
         * @param graphAuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient created by AAD Boot starter. Used to surface the access token.
         */
        public GraphAuthenticationProvider(@Nonnull OAuth2AuthorizedClient graphAuthorizedClient) {
            this.graphAuthorizedClient = graphAuthorizedClient;
        }

        /**
         * This implementation of the IAuthenticationProvider helps injects the Graph access
         * token into the headers of the request that GraphServiceClient makes.
         *
         * @param requestUrl the outgoing request URL
         * @return a future with the token
         */
        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(@Nonnull final URL requestUrl){
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(graphAuthorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
        }
    }
```

however im getting the error

Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient.getAccessToken()" because "this.graphAuthorizedClient" is null

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.authorization-clients.graph.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
```